# Make SOAP request and insert duplicate values on database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, web-services, soap

I make a soap request in php, and I get the response from request and insert the values of the response in my database. I use my browser to run the script but something strange happens when I copy the link to another tab and run it, because when I check my database the values are duplicate. Sometimes when run the script the values are not duplicate in my database at the moment, but the next day the values are duplicate, and I don't understand why.

soap_request.php

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','utf8');
$init_today = date("Y-m-d");

$xml = 'soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:def="http://****/definitions" xmlns:cul="http:/***/****/***">
   <soapenv:Header>'....;

$soapUrl = "https://****/Culture"; // asmx URL of WSDL

$headers = array(
  ...
  "SOAPAction: http://****/****/****/*****", 
  "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
);

$url = $soapUrl;
// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
...

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$string = str_replace(array('ns1:', 'ns2:', 'ns3:'), array('', '', ''), $response);
$content = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","***","*****");

function insertEventId($con, $content){

    $array_id = array();
    foreach($content->xpath('//Event') as $header){
        $result = ($header->xpath('Id'));

        $event_id = (string) $result[0];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO eventos_sapo (event_id) VALUES ('$event_id')";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            echo $sql . "</br>";
            //echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
        }
        array_push($array_id, $event_id);

    }

    return $array_id;

}

function insertTitulo($con, $content, $array_id){
    $count = 0;
    while($count < sizeof($array_id)){
        foreach($array_id as $id){
            $count_aux = 0;
            foreach($content->xpath('//Event') as $header){
                $result = ($header->xpath('Name')); // Should output 'something'.
                if($result){
                    $titulo = (string) $result[0];
                    if($count == $count_aux){
                        $sql = "Update eventos_sapo set titulo='$titulo' where event_id='$id';";
                        mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
                        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                            echo $sql . "</br>";
                            //echo "New record created successfully";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                        }
                    }
                }
                $count_aux++;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
$array_id = insertEventId($con, $content);
insertTitulo($con, $content, $array_id);
```

Response of request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://***/**/***" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://***.****.**/***/**" xmlns:ns3="http://**.**.**/**/**">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetAgendaV2Response>
         <ns1:GetAgendaV2Result>
            <ns1:Events>
               <ns1:Event>
                  <ns1:Id>94343</ns1:Id>
                  <ns1:Name>Mexa-se Mais 2011 - Orientação no Jamor (BTT e Caminhada)</ns1:Name>
                  <ns1:Genre>
                     <ns1:Id>10</ns1:Id>
                     <ns1:Name>Outdoor</ns1:Name>
                  </ns1:Genre>
               </ns1:Event>
               <ns1:Event>
                  <ns1:Id>122611</ns1:Id>
                  <ns1:Name>«Memória da Politécnica: Quatro Séculos de Educação, Ciência e Cultura»</ns1:Name>
                  <ns1:Genre>
                     <ns1:Id>6</ns1:Id>
                     <ns1:Name>Exposições</ns1:Name>
                  </ns1:Genre>
               </ns1:Event>
             ....
```

Comment: As you don't prevent duplicate insertion, there are duplicates. I do not think it is that hard to understand. Perhaps you don't see the wood for the trees?

Comment: OK and make that prevention in my script PHP?

Comment: You can prevent duplicates for example by checking if the data already is in the database before adding it again. Most database servers already offer some functionality to prevent duplication of data by defintion.

Comment: ENforce the uniqueness on the database always. Don't do this via PHP.